# Take totals of sales of distributors, and get the percentage of each distributor on the total of sales overall for all distributors

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to take totals of each movie from different distributors, turn those totals into percentages of the entirety of totals combined for all distributors. Then I need to take every distributor thats under 1% and combine all of those into a different distributor called other.

There are 100+ distributors, take a total of sales overall and create percentages for each distribution instead of the number of sales.
This is the output for the following code below.

```
print(df.groupby(df['Distributor'])['Tickets Sold'].sum())

Distributor
20th Century Fox                    141367982
25th Frame                               2989
26 Aries                                  867
A24                                   6494901
Abramorama Films                       367311
Anchor Bay Entertainment                12710
Archstone Entertainment                  1299
Area 23a                                 4615
ArtAffects                              48549
ArtMattan Productions                     319
```

Answer (score 1):

Create boolean mask by compare `sum` with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for `<`, filter by inverted mask by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and add new value by [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) and `sum` of filtered rows under `1%`:

```
mask = df.div(df.sum()).lt(0.01)
out = df[~mask]
out.loc['others'] = df[mask].sum()
print (out)
20th Century Fox    141367982
A24                   6494901
others                 438659
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is there any way i can take this data and sort both Distributor name and tickets sold in order from greatest to least?

Comment: @Hoonin Not sure, if understand. Do you need change my answer by `out = df[~mask]` to `out = df[~mask].sort_values(ascending=False)` by `sums`?  or sorting by `out = out.sort_values(ascending=False)` before `print(out)` if need sorting final data?

Comment: I went it a different way, df=df.groupby(df['Distributor'])['Tickets Sold'].sum()
df1=df[df.div(df.sum()).lt(0.01)]
df2=df.drop(df1.index)
yourdf=pd.concat([df2,pd.Series(df1.sum(),index=['Others'])])

Comment: yourdf = yourdf.sort_values(ascending=False)
print(yourdf)
yourdf2 = yourdf.drop(columns=['Tickets Sold'], axis=1)
print(yourdf2)

Comment: how can i take the now sorted data, and remove the tickets sold column of data, for the next part i need to remove it and only use the names, or how can i access just the names and not the numbers.